# simple regex for italian words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I can't understand a simple regex that I need for a control over a `preg_match` statment:

-I need that every words with even white space between, and accent and apostrophe are allowed

so something like: `sjsjsjjsjsjs òòòò èèèèè   ddddd '''   eerfk jefrkj sdc` should be accepted

so i write something like: `[a-zA-Z\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27\s]*`

that take everything that is letters and some special HEX code for accent and apostrophe, but i can't understand how to concatenate the sentence:

```
[^\r\n]
```

I'd like to reject anything if there is an end of line or a return statement. The puntaction too but it seem to be allreafy solved with my regex
so something like:

```
adjnasdnjadsija adokasmdoasdmoa admoadsoasodoas END
sddaadsasd òòò
```

should be accepted until the words END
Is it the right code? i made several test but no result! 
I test my regex over http://regex101.com/

Comment: code sample: <?php
`if (preg_match("/[a-zA-Z\xE0\xE8\xE9\xF9\xF2\xEC\x27\s]*/", "something aaaa ;")) {
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "bad string";
}
?>`
just going on ok even if there is a ;

Answer (score 2):

Set the locale appropriately:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"it_IT");
```

Now you can use a much simpler regex:

```
/[\w\s]*/
```

This is because `\w` is locale-aware ^_^

Comment: ok alternative solution but im still not able to do a simple thing with a simple regex...

Comment: Are you using it right? If you're `preg_match`ing that, it'll pass on any input because an empty match is acceptable in that regex.

Comment: I set the local like you said and then put preg_match in an if steatment...but it pass simbols like" . , ; : etc."

Comment: That's because `/[\w\s]*/` matches everything. You're supposed to check the captured match.